# Android: Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-package-managers

I am trying to understand the internal handling of permissions(normal) during install time i.e how they are granted.

On searching I have found no satisfactory answers and also most of the search resulted in working of run time permissions. I have found that PackageManagerService handles it but there is no explanation.

So if anyone can explain me the flow or handling of normal permissions I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What kind of flow are you looking for? Normal permissions are granted automatically and cannot be denied. No action needs to be performed except for declaring them in the manifest.

Comment: I want to know which classes are involved in granting the normal permissions. I came to know it starts with PackageManagerService class but after that I don't have any idea